# ¿Como hago formularios para 2 fotos en php?

Tags: formularios

'''

```
    <input type="photo" name="foto1" >

    <input type="photo" name="fo2o2">
    
    <input type="text" name="carpeta" placeholder="">

    <input type="submit" value="Guardar">

</form>
```

'''
**NO SE COMO COMPLETAR EL FORMULARIO PARA QUE ME FUNCIONE CORRECTAMENTE**

Comment: MDN: [input type file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) Puedes poner múltiples inputs si deseas.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  action="ejemplo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="file" name="foto">

            <input type="file" name="foto2">

            <input type="text"  name="carpeta" placeholder="">

            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="btn">

  </form>
```

**Esta es una de las formas**